How can I fix my 3d rotation cards animation so my header and footer aren't smooshed togeather?
I'm trying to make a website for my husbands business. I have been messing around with different looks and layouts and he really likes this card animation but it messed up my entire page now my header and footer and h1 and h2 content are all smooched in with the 3d card rotation. Any help would be greatly appreciated!


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Kumbh Sans', sans-serif;
}


/* spline interactive */


/*
.background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: scale(1.3);
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: -1;
  
}
*/

.navbar {
  background: #1f456e;
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}

.navbar__container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 80px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 50px;
}


/*Moving img/logo to the top left*/

.logo_navbar {
  position: flex;
  height: flex;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100px;
}

#navbar__logo {
  background-color: #f99185;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #fde7b1 0%, #ff6700 100%);
  background-size: 100%;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.fa-g {
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}

.navbar__menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar__item {
  height: 80px;
}

.navbar__links {
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  height: 100%;
}

.navbar__btn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #f9b279;
  color: #fff;
}

.button:hover {
  background: #f77062;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.navbar__links:hover {
  color: #f77062;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  .navbar__container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 80px;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1300px;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .navbar__menu {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1000px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    height: 50vh;
    z-index: -1;
    background: #1f456e;
  }
  .navbar__menu.active {
    background: #1f456e;
    top: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    z-index: 99;
    height: 50vh;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
  }
  #navbar__logo {
    padding-left: 25px;
  }
  .navbar__toggle .bar {
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    margin: 5px auto;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    background: #fff;
  }
  .navbar__item {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar__links {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2rem;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
  }
  #mobile-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    right: 5%;
    transform: translate(5%, 20%);
  }
  .navbar__btn {
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
  }
  .button {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .navbar__toggle .bar {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #mobile-menu.is-active .bar:nth-child(2) {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  #mobile-menu.is-active .bar:nth-child(1) {
    transform: translateY(8px) rotate(45deg);
  }
  #mobile-menu.is-active .bar:nth-child(3) {
    transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
  }
}


/* Hero Section CSS */

.main {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.main__container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  justify-self: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 90vh;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1300px;
  padding: 0 50px;
}

.main__content h1 {
  font-size: 4rem;
  background-color: #ff8177;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #ffba87 0%, #ff8a35 100%);
  background-size: 100%;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.main__content h2 {
  font-size: 4rem;
  background-color: #ff8177;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #d85b00 0%, hsl(25, 95%, 83%) 100%);
  background-size: 100%;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.main__content p {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
}

.main__btn {
  font-size: 1rem;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #f77062 0%, #fe5196 100%);
  padding: 14px 32px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.35s;
  outline: none;
}

.main__btn a {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.main__btn:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: #1f456e;
  transition: all 0.35s;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.main__btn:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.main__btn:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}

.main__img--container {
  text-align: center;
}

#main__img {
  height: 80%;
  width: 80%;
}


/* Mobile Responsive */

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .main__container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto;
    align-items: center;
    justify-self: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 90vh;
  }
  .main__content {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 4rem;
  }
  .main__content h1 {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    margin-top: 2rem;
  }
  .main__content h2 {
    font-size: 3rem;
  }
  .main__content p {
    margin-top: 1rem;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
}

@media and (max-width: 480px) {
  .main__content h1 {
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin-top: 3rem;
  }
  .main__content h2 {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
  .main__content p {
    margin-top: 2rem;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
  .main__btn {
    padding: 12px 36px;
    margin: 2.5rem 0;
  }
}


/* Services Section CSS */

.services {
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.services h1 {
  background-color: #ff8177;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ff8177 0%, #ff867a 0%, #ff8c7f 21%, #f99185 52%, #cf556c 78%, #b12a5b 100%);
  background-size: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 5rem;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.services__container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}


/*
.services__card {
    margin: 1rem;
    height: 525px;
    width: 400px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,
     rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)0%, rgba(17,17,17,0.6)100%), 
     url('/images/pic2.jpg');
     background-size: cover;
     position: relative;
     color: #fff;
}

.services__card:nth-child(2) {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)0%, rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.6)100%),
     url('/images/pic3.jpg');
}
*/

.services h2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 350px;
  left: 30px;
}


/*
.services__card p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 400px;
  left: 30px;
}

.services__card button {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #f77062;
  position: absolute;
  top: 440px;
  left: 30px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.services__card:hover {
  transform:scale(1.075);
  transition: 0.2s ease-in;
  cursor: pointer;
}
*/

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  .services {
    height: 1600px;
  }
  .services h1 {
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin-top: 12rem;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .services {
    height: 1400px;
  }
  .serives h1 {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }
  .services__card {
    width: 300px;
  }
}


/*
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*/

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: white;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  animation: animate 20s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(360deg);
  }
}

.box span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateY(calc(var(--i) *45deg)) translateZ(400px);
  -webkit-box-reflect: below 0px linear-gradient(transparent, transparent, #fff);
}

.box span img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 18px;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}


/* Footer CSS */

.footer__container {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5rem 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#footer__logo {
  background-color: #f99185;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #fde7b1 0%, #ff6700 100%);
  background-size: 100%;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.footer__links {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.footer__link--wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.footer__link--items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin: 16px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 160px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.footer__link--items h2 {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.footer__link--items>h2 {
  color: #141414;
}

.footer__link--items a {
  color: #141414;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.footer__link--items a:hover {
  color: #e9e9e9;
  transition: 0.3s ease-out;
}


/* Social Icons*/

.social__icon--link {
  color: purple;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.social__media {
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
}

.social__media--wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 40px auto 0 auto;
}

.social__icons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 240px;
}

.social__logo {
  color: #fff;
  justify-self: flex-start;
  margin-left: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.website__rights {
  color: #141414;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 820px) {
  .footer__links {
    padding-top: 2rem;
  }
  #footer__logo {
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
  }
  .website__rights {
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
  }
  .footer__link--wrapper {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .social__media--wrap {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .footer__link--items {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>BrightSide Solar</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a3a76a0b5c.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kumbh+Sans:wght@100..900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="3dcards" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>


  <!-- Navbar Section -->
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar__container">

      <a href="/" id="navbar__logo"><img src="/images/2.png" class="logo_navbar"></img> BrightSide Solar</a>
      <div class="navbar__toggle" id="mobile-menu">
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
      </div>
      <ul class="navbar__menu">
        <li class="navbar__item">
          <a href="/" class="navbar__links">
        Home
       </a>
        </li>
        <li class="navbar__item">
          <a href="/AboutUs.html" class="navbar__links">
            Our Company
        </a>
        </li>
        <li class="navbar__item">
          <a href="/AboutUs.html" class="navbar__links">
            Learn about Us
        </a>
        </li>
        <li class="navbar__btn">
          <a href="/" class="button">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!--Hero Section -->
  <div class="main">
    <div class="main__container">
      <div class="main__content">
        <h1>Brightside Solar</h1>
        <h2>Our Work</h2>
        <p>See what makes us different</p>
        <button class="main__btn"><a href="/">Get Started</a></button>
      </div>
      <!--
       <div class="main__img--container">
        <img src="images/pic1.svg" alt="pic" id="main__img">
       </div>
    -->
      <!--3d cards-->
      <div class="box">
        <span style="--i: 1"><img src="3dimages/1.jpg"></span>
        <span style="--i: 2"><img src="3dimages/2.jpg"></span>
        <span style="--i: 3"><img src="3dimages/3.jpg"></span>
        <span style="--i: 4"><img src="3dimages/4.jpg"></span>
        <span style="--i: 5"><img src="3dimages/5.jpg"></span>
        <span style="--i: 6"><img src="3dimages/6.jpg"></span>
        <span style="--i: 7"><img src="3dimages/7.jpg"></span>
        <span style="--i: 8"><img src="3dimages/8.jpg"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--Services Section-->
  <!--
<div class="services">
  <h1>See what the hype is about</h1>
 <div class="services__container">
   <div class="services__card">
    <h2>Experience Bliss</h2>
    <p>AI Powered Technology</p>
    <button>Get Started</button>
   </div> 
<div class="services__card">
    <h2>Are you Ready?</h2>
    <p>Take the leap</p>
    <button>Get Started</button>
</div>
 </div>   
</div>
-->

  <!--Footer Section-->
  <div class="footer__container">
    <div class="footer__links">
      <div class="footer__link--wrapper">
        <div class="footer__link--items">
          <h2>About Us</h2>
          <a href="/sign__up">How it works</a>
          <a href="/">Testimonales</a>
          <a href="/">Careers</a>
          <a href="/">Investments</a>
          <a href="/">Terms of Service</a>
        </div>
        <div class="footer__link--items">
          <h2>Contact Us</h2>
          <a href="/">Contact</a>
          <a href="/">Support</a>
          <a href="/">Destinations</a>
          <a href="/">Sponsorships</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer__link--wrapper">
        <div class="footer__link--items">
          <h2>Videos</h2>
          <a href="/">Submit Video</a>
          <a href="/">Ambassadors</a>
          <a href="/">Agency</a>
          <a href="/">Influencer</a>
        </div>
        <div class="footer__link--items">
          <h2>Social Media</h2>
          <a href="/">Instagram</a>
          <a href="/">Facebook</a>
          <a href="/">Youtube</a>
          <a href="/">Twitter</a>
          <a href="/">Google</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="social__media">
      <div class="social__media--wrap">
        <div class="footer__logo">
          <a href="/" id="footer__logo"><img src="/images/2.png" class="logo_navbar"></img> BrightSide Solar</a>
        </div>
        <p class="website__rights">&copy; BrightSide Solar 2024.All rights reserved</p>
        <div class="social__icons">
          <a href="/" class="social__icon--link" target="_blank">
            <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
          </a>
          <a href="/" class="social__icon--link" target="_blank">
            <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
          </a>
          <a href="/" class="social__icon--link" target="_blank">
            <i class="fab fa-x"></i>
          </a>
          <a href="/" class="social__icon--link" target="_blank">
            <i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i>
          </a>
          <a href="/" class="social__icon--link" target="_blank">
            <i class="fab fa-youtube"></i>
          </a>
          <a href="/" class="social__icon--link" target="_blank">
            <i class="fab fa-google"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>




Please provide minimal reproducible example).

Your HTML is invalid. The <img> element is self-closing and does not use a closing </img>

Add flex-direction: column; to your body and remove grid-template-columns from .main__container.


* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Kumbh Sans', sans-serif;
}

/* spline interactive */
/*
.background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: scale(1.3);
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: -1;
  
}
*/
.navbar {
    background: #1f456e;
    height: 80px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}

.navbar__container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 80px;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 50px;
}

/*Moving img/logo to the top left*/

.logo_navbar{
  position: flex;
  height: flex;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100px;
}

#navbar__logo {
    background-color: #f99185;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #fde7b1 0%, #ff6700 100%);
    background-size: 100%;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.fa-g {
   margin-right: 0.5rem; 
}

.navbar__menu {
  display: flex; 
  align-items: center; 
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar__item {
    height: 80px; 
}

.navbar__links {
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;  
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  height: 100%;
}

.navbar__btn {
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.button {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #f9b279;
    color: #fff;
}

.button:hover {
  background: #f77062;  
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.navbar__links:hover {
    color: #f77062;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  .navbar__container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 80px;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1300px;
    padding: 0;
  }  

  .navbar__menu {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1000px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    height: 50vh;
    z-index: -1;
    background: #1f456e;
  }

  .navbar__menu.active {
    background: #1f456e;
    top: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    z-index: 99;
    height: 50vh;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
  }

  #navbar__logo {
    padding-left: 25px;
  }

  .navbar__toggle .bar {
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    margin: 5px auto;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    background: #fff;
  }

  .navbar__item {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .navbar__links {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2rem;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
  }

  #mobile-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    right: 5%;
    transform: translate(5%, 20%);
  }

  .navbar__btn {
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
  }

  .button {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 0;
  }

  .navbar__toggle .bar {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  #mobile-menu.is-active .bar:nth-child(2) {
    opacity: 0;
  }

   #mobile-menu.is-active .bar:nth-child(1) {
       transform: translateY(8px) rotate(45deg);
   }

   #mobile-menu.is-active .bar:nth-child(3) {
       transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
   }
}

/* Hero Section CSS */
.main {
    background-color: #fff;
}

.main__container {
   display: grid; 
   /* grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;  */
   align-items: center;
   justify-self: center;
   margin: 0 auto;
   height: 90vh;
   background-color: #fff;
   z-index: 1;
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 1300px;
   padding: 0 50px;
}

.main__content h1 {
    font-size: 4rem;
    background-color: #ff8177;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #ffba87 0%, #ff8a35 100%);
    background-size: 100%;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.main__content h2 {
    font-size: 4rem;
    background-color: #ff8177;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #d85b00 0%, hsl(25, 95%, 83%) 100%);
    background-size: 100%;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.main__content p {
  margin-top: 1rem;  
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
}

.main__btn {
    font-size: 1rem;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #f77062 0%, #fe5196 100%);
    padding: 14px 32px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 2rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0.35s;
    outline: none;
}

.main__btn a {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.main__btn:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background: #1f456e;
    transition: all 0.35s;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.main__btn:hover {
    color: #fff;
}

.main__btn:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}
    
.main__img--container {
    text-align: center;
}

#main__img {
    height: 80%;
    width: 80%;
}

/* Mobile Responsive */
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .main__container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto;
    align-items: center;
    justify-self: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 90vh;
  }
  
  .main__content {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 4rem;
  }

  .main__content h1 {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    margin-top: 2rem;
  }

  .main__content h2 {
    font-size: 3rem;
  }

  .main__content p {
    margin-top: 1rem;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
}

@media  and (max-width: 480px) {
.main__content h1 {
        font-size: 2rem;
        margin-top: 3rem;
    }

    .main__content h2 {
        font-size: 2rem;
    }

    .main__content p {
        margin-top: 2rem;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
    }

.main__btn {
    padding: 12px 36px;
    margin: 2.5rem 0;
}
}

/* Services Section CSS */
.services {
    background: white;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

.services h1 {
    background-color: #ff8177;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ff8177 0%, 
    #ff867a 0%, #ff8c7f 21%, #f99185 52%, #cf556c 78%,
    #b12a5b 100%);
    background-size: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 5rem;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.services__container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

/*
.services__card {
    margin: 1rem;
    height: 525px;
    width: 400px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,
     rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)0%, rgba(17,17,17,0.6)100%), 
     url('/images/pic2.jpg');
     background-size: cover;
     position: relative;
     color: #fff;
}

.services__card:nth-child(2) {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)0%, rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.6)100%),
     url('/images/pic3.jpg');
}
*/
.services h2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 350px;
    left: 30px;
}
/*
.services__card p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 400px;
  left: 30px;
}

.services__card button {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #f77062;
  position: absolute;
  top: 440px;
  left: 30px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.services__card:hover {
  transform:scale(1.075);
  transition: 0.2s ease-in;
  cursor: pointer;
}
*/
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  .services {
    height: 1600px;
  }

  .services h1 {
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin-top: 12rem;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .services {
    height: 1400px;
  }

  .serives h1 {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }

  .services__card {
    width: 300px;
  }
}
/*
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*/
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: white;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  animation: animate 20s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(0deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(360deg);
  }


}

.box span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateY(calc(var(--i) *45deg)) translateZ(400px);
  -webkit-box-reflect: below 0px linear-gradient(transparent, transparent, #fff);
}

.box span img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 18px;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;

}
/* Footer CSS */
.footer__container {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5rem 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#footer__logo {
  background-color: #f99185;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #fde7b1 0%, #ff6700 100%);
    background-size: 100%;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2rem;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.footer__links {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.footer__link--wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.footer__link--items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin: 16px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 160px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.footer__link--items h2 {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.footer__link--items > h2 {
  color: #141414;
}

.footer__link--items a {
  color: #141414;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.footer__link--items a:hover {
  color: #e9e9e9;
  transition: 0.3s ease-out;
}

/* Social Icons*/
.social__icon--link {
  color: purple;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.social__media {
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
}

.social__media--wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 40px auto 0 auto;
}

.social__icons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 240px;
}

.social__logo {
  color: #fff;
  justify-self: flex-start;
  margin-left: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.website__rights {
  color: #141414;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 820px) {
  .footer__links {
    padding-top: 2rem;
  }

  #footer__logo {
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
  }

  .website__rights {
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
  }

  .footer__link--wrapper {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .social__media--wrap {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .footer__link--items {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
<!-- Navbar Section -->
   <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar__container">
         
    <a href="/" id="navbar__logo"><img src="/images/2.png" class="logo_navbar"></img> BrightSide Solar</a>
    <div class="navbar__toggle" id="mobile-menu">
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    </div>
    <ul class="navbar__menu">
    <li class="navbar__item">
       <a href="/" class="navbar__links">
        Home
       </a>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar__item">
        <a href="/AboutUs.html" class="navbar__links">
            Our Company
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar__item">
        <a href="/AboutUs.html" class="navbar__links">
            Learn about Us
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar__btn">
        <a href="/" class="button">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
   </nav>

   <!--Hero Section -->
   <div class="main">
    <div class="main__container">
      <div class="main__content">
        <h1>Brightside Solar</h1>
        <h2>Our Work</h2>
        <p>See what makes us different</p>
        <button class="main__btn"><a href="/">Get Started</a></button>
      </div> 
      <!--
       <div class="main__img--container">
        <img src="images/pic1.svg" alt="pic" id="main__img">
       </div>
    -->
       <!--3d cards-->
       <div class="box">
        <span style="--i: 1"><img src="3dimages/1.jpg"></span>
        <span style="--i: 2"><img src="3dimages/2.jpg"></span>
        <span style="--i: 3"><img src="3dimages/3.jpg"></span>
        <span style="--i: 4"><img src="3dimages/4.jpg"></span>
        <span style="--i: 5"><img src="3dimages/5.jpg"></span>
        <span style="--i: 6"><img src="3dimages/6.jpg"></span>
        <span style="--i: 7"><img src="3dimages/7.jpg"></span>
        <span style="--i: 8"><img src="3dimages/8.jpg"></span>
       </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <!--Services Section-->
   <!--
<div class="services">
  <h1>See what the hype is about</h1>
 <div class="services__container">
   <div class="services__card">
    <h2>Experience Bliss</h2>
    <p>AI Powered Technology</p>
    <button>Get Started</button>
   </div> 
<div class="services__card">
    <h2>Are you Ready?</h2>
    <p>Take the leap</p>
    <button>Get Started</button>
</div>
 </div>   
</div>
-->

<!--Footer Section-->
<div class="footer__container">
    <div class="footer__links">
      <div class="footer__link--wrapper">
        <div class="footer__link--items">
           <h2>About Us</h2>
           <a href="/sign__up">How it works</a> 
           <a href="/">Testimonales</a> 
           <a href="/">Careers</a> 
           <a href="/">Investments</a> 
           <a href="/">Terms of Service</a> 
        </div>
        <div class="footer__link--items">
            <h2>Contact Us</h2>
            <a href="/">Contact</a>
            <a href="/">Support</a>
            <a href="/">Destinations</a>
            <a href="/">Sponsorships</a>
        </div>
      </div> 
    <div class="footer__link--wrapper">
        <div class="footer__link--items">
            <h2>Videos</h2>
            <a href="/">Submit Video</a>
            <a href="/">Ambassadors</a>
            <a href="/">Agency</a>
            <a href="/">Influencer</a>
        </div>
        <div class="footer__link--items">
            <h2>Social Media</h2>
            <a href="/">Instagram</a>
            <a href="/">Facebook</a>
            <a href="/">Youtube</a>
            <a href="/">Twitter</a>
            <a href="/">Google</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="social__media">
       <div class="social__media--wrap">
        <div class="footer__logo">
        <a href="/" id="footer__logo"><img src="/images/2.png" class="logo_navbar"></img> BrightSide Solar</a>
        </div>
        <p class="website__rights">&copy; BrightSide Solar 2024.All rights reserved</p>
        <div class="social__icons">
           <a href="/" class="social__icon--link" target="_blank">
            <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
           </a> 
        <a href="/" class="social__icon--link" target="_blank">
            <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="/" class="social__icon--link" target="_blank">
            <i class="fab fa-x"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="/" class="social__icon--link" target="_blank">
            <i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="/" class="social__icon--link" target="_blank">
            <i class="fab fa-youtube"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="/" class="social__icon--link" target="_blank">
            <i class="fab fa-google"></i>
        </a>
        </div>
       </div> 
    </div>
</div>




Where is the body? "Add flex-direction: column; to your body" is that in my html or CSS? I'm still new to web development. so i really apricate the help! I haven't gotten this far into my schooling on course careers so I've been having to rely on you tube tutorial's. Thank you again for helping me. I'm trying to make the text H1 & H2 left of the 3d pictures so there on the same line & lvl. If that's not possible then if i could make the 3d pics under the text but the 3d pictures in the middle and not to the left of the page.

The <body> is in your HTML and you are styling it by adding body {...} in CSS. Find that rule in your CSS file and add this extra line to it: flex-direction: column;.
If you want to center the 3d pictures: add margin: 0 auto; to the .box {...} in CSS.

It would be a best practice not to add styles to the body. Better to create a container in it that wraps all the elements that are in <body> and copy the styles from body {...} to this new container.
